# 2Ceckout not showing paypal option

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, 2checkout

I am integrating 2checkout on my website but its showing only creditcard charging option there is no option for paypal how can i enable paypal?

[image]

HTML Form:

```
<form id="2checkout" action="https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="sid" value="123123123312"/>
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="2CO"/>
<input type="hidden" name="li_0_name" value="Test Product"/>
<input type="hidden" name="li_0_price" value="10.01"/>
<input type="hidden" name="card_holder_name" value="Testing Tester"/>
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="no-reply@2co.com"/>
<input type="hidden" name="street_address" value="123 test st"/>
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="Columbus"/>
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="Ohio"/>
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="43123"/>
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="USA"/>
<input type='hidden' name='demo' value='Y' />
<input type="submit" value="Click Here!" />
</form>
<script src="https://www.2checkout.com/static/checkout/javascript/direct.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems like a question for 2checkout's support. At a basic level, read its documentation and ensure you've configured PayPal as a payment method in its settings interface for your account, and particularly bearing in mind the fact that this is in "demo" mode, which may have its own setup vs. live. You may need a PayPal sandbox account, depending on what 2checkout's demo settings call for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this input:

```
<input type='hidden' name='paypal_direct' value='Y' />
```